# Symfony2 and Extjs4 integration

Tags: extjs, symfony, extjs4

I tried to use a Extjs MVC app as a frontend to symfony2 website. I load extjs lib and my app.js :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Cc',
    appFolder: '/bundles/mybundle/js/app',
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    controllers: [
    ],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Cc.view.Viewport');
    }
});
```

in my app folder there is the Viewport.js but when I load the app I have 403 error. I use assets as describe in sf doc (with the command line to publish them in /web)

Comment: I think you are using custom viewport! ``

Comment: Try accessing the assets directly in your browser and see what the result is. In most cases the rewrite rules and/or routes in symfony aren't set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

It was ok after I check permissions on my app folder...